# overflow: hidden + position: fixed parent - view child with position: absolute

Tags: html, css, frontend

I need to show child block, which positioned absolutely in parent block, which have **fixed position** and `overflow: hidden` property:

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGLvk/3/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 175px;
}
```

It works if parent have a `position: static` and fixed height. Or, if child have a `position: fixed`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it up by wrapping your `.parent` div inside a `.grandparent` div and transferring the `position:fixed;` attribute to the grandparent, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jGLvk/1159/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grandparent{
    position:fixed;
}

.parent {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 175px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try position: relative on parent Element.